# How to move one JFrame into another JFrame while hiding one JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

How to move one javax.Swing program into another program of the Swing while hiding one Swing program and how to make scrollable JFrame. Please help me.

Comment: I do understand that not everyone is gifted with English language skills, but honestly, my random word generator can build a better sentence...

Comment: Hello Max I let English is good but when we ask our query that time we did not know how to express their thoughts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you can find a very [good example code](http://java2everyone.blogspot.com/2008/12/add-scrollbar-to-jframe.html) to add JScrollBar to JFrame.

Comment: @mKorbel: See [Writing Good Link Text](http://www.yorku.ca/webacces/simplestrategies/10_linktext.html)

Comment: agreed ++, but in cotrast with good approach please see great posts/answers by @StanislavL (http://stackoverflow.com/users/301607/stanislavl), then where is true, these answer contains all that most of us ...., agreed very sesitive, never closable and always opened thema

Comment: @Jonas  That page alludes to something I typically try to do with links.  That is, use the page title as the link text. *"For more details & working examples, see [How to Use Trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)".*  Whoever titled the page put some thought into what the page was about (usually).  Of course, you used the exact same technique in your link.  ;)